# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "data" of relation "WorldBank_projects" does not exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, api, django-models

I'm working on a Django application which fetches JSON data from an API and stores it in PostgreSQL database. But while migrating the app I'm getting these errors:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "data" of relation "WorldBank_projects" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "WorldBank_projects" ("data", "project_id", "pro...
```

What should I change in code to resolve this error? 
Here's the traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "data" of relation "WorldBank_projects" does not exist
    LINE 1: INSERT INTO "WorldBank_projects" ("data", "project_id", "pro...
                                          ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/aggregator/WorldBank/management/commands/fetch_wb.py", line 53, in handle
    project_abstract = data['project_abstract']
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 962, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1107, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "data" of relation "WorldBank_projects" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "WorldBank_projects" ("data", "project_id", "pro...
```

How to fix this problem?

Here's my code for models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Projects(models.Model):
        data = JSONField(null=False)
        project_id=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        project_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        status=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        country=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        locations=JSONField()
        mjtheme=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        project_docs=JSONField()
        source=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        mjtheme_namecode=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        docty=models.TextField()
        countryname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        countrycode=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        themecode=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        theme_namecode=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        project_url=models.TextField()
        totalcommamt=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        mjthemecode=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        sector1=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        theme1=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        theme2=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        theme3=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        projectinfo=models.TextField()
        country_namecode=models.CharField(max_length=5)
        p2a_updated_date=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        p2a_flag=models.CharField(max_length=5)
        project_abstract=JSONField()
```

And here's the code for fetch.py file which is stored under /management/commands/fetch.py:

```
import requests
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from aggregator.WorldBank.models import Projects

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        response = requests.get("https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects?format=json&countryshortname_exact=India&source=IBRD&kw=N&rows=7")
        data = response.json()
        projects = data['projects']

        for project in projects:
            print(projects[project])
            print("\n\n")

            data = projects[project]

            Projects.objects.create(

                project_id = data['id'],
                project_name = data['project_name'],
                status = data['status'],
                country = data['countryshortname'],
                locations = data['locations'],
                mjtheme = data['mjtheme'],
                project_docs = data['projectdocs'],
                source = data['source'],
                mjtheme_namecode = data['mjtheme_namecode'],
                docty = data['docty'],
                countryname = data['countryname'],
                countrycode = data['countrycode'],
                themecode = data['themecode'],
                theme_namecode = data['theme_namecode'],
                project_url = data['url'],
                totalcommamt = data['totalcommamt'],
                mjthemecode = data['mjthemecode'],
                sector1 = data['sector1'],
                theme1 = data['theme1'],
                theme2 = data['theme2'],
                theme3 = data['theme3'],
                projectinfo = data['projectinfo'],
                country_namecode = ['country_namecode'],
                p2a_updated_date = data['p2a_updated_date'],
                p2a_flag = data['p2a_flag'],
                project_abstract = data['project_abstract']

                )
```

Comment: Have you created and run schema migrations?

Comment: Your `Projects.objects.create()` doesn't include `data` field.

Comment: @Borut what fields should I create in Projects.objects.create() according to the JSON responce?

Comment: @HåkenLid what I did is 1) python manage.py makemigrations 2)python manage.py migrate

Comment: @HåkenLid how to do schema migrations?

Comment: In models you have a field `data = JSONField(null=False)` and in your `Projects.objects.create()` it's missing.

Comment: @Borut so how should I include data = JSONField(null = False) into Projects.objects.create( ) I don't how to create this specific field. because json response is different

Comment: @Borut I'm also getting key errors for some fields